При запуске теста такая ошибка: Module './Button' was resolved to 'ссылка на компонент' , but '--jsx' is not set
Проблема с import, при запуска теста поялвяютеся ошибки. Если тестировать обычный ts файл все в порядке.
import {Button} from "./Button.tsx";
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react";

describe('classNames', () => {
    test('with only first params', () => {
        render(<Button>TEST</Button>)
        expect(screen.getByText('TEST')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })

})


Error:
Test suite failed to run

    src/shared/ui/Button/Button.test.tsx:1:22 - error TS6142: Module './Button.tsx' was resolved to 'C:/Users/uldar/WebstormProjects/barton_v2/src/shared/ui/Button/Button.tsx', but '--jsx' is not set.

    1 import {Button} from "./Button.tsx";
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/shared/ui/Button/Button.test.tsx:6:16 - error TS17004: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.

    6         render(<Button>TEST</Button>)
                     ~~~~~~~~
    src/shared/ui/Button/Button.test.tsx:7:42 - error TS2339: Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElement>'.

    7         expect(screen.getByText('TEST')).toBeInTheDocument();

Пробовал менять в jest.config.ts transformIgnorePatterns и transform. Ошибка не изменилась. Добавлял tsconfig.json esModuleInteror: true. Перезапускал IDE.
moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "mjs",
    "cjs",
    "jsx",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],

  preset: "ts-jest",
  transform: {
    '^.+\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv:
      ['<rootDir>/setupTests.ts'],



Добавьте содержимое tsconfig.json (кнопка "Править" находится под вопросом)

@AndreiKhotko добавил в виде скриншота, так как стак оверфлоу не позволяет ввести столько кода

Сайт позволяет ввести такое количество кода. У вас его не так много. Наверно, вы что-то не так сделали. Я бы попробовал вручную воспроизвести проблему, но переписывать tsconfig с картинки я точно не буду :)
